# UISearchController display issue - iPhone X and Other devices

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I've implemented `UISearchController` and presenting it on `UIViewController`.

Navigation bar has `search` button and on clicking search, `UISearchController` will present from top of the screen.

**Issue is, In iPhone X it looks fine but in all other devices it doesn't fit  properly with spacing.**

[image]

My implementation is like this :

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = SEARCH
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x2A3442)
searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

// Search bar UI change
for subview in searchController.searchBar.subviews {
    for innerSubview in subview.subviews {
        if innerSubview is UITextField {
            let textField = innerSubview as? UITextField
            textField?.textColor = UIColor.white
            textField?.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            textField?.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x38465A)
        }
    }
}

present(searchController, animated: true)
```